# does "about four inches square" refers to "some phosphorescent material" or "hand"?

Tags: meaning, reference

does "about four inches square" refers to "some phosphorescent material" or "hand"?

> very extraordinary phase of Mrs. Fox-Jensen's mediumship was the
>   production of luminous substances. In the presence of Mrs. Makdougall
>   Gregory, Mr. W. H. Harrison, the editor of a London newspaper, and
>   others, a hand appeared carrying some phosphorescent material, **about
>   four inches square**, with which the floor was struck and a sitter's
>   face touched.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: Some phosphorescent material.

Comment: Hands are not usually square....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependent clauses like this almost always refer to the closest preceding noun, so in this case, since the clause comes right after "some phosphorescent material", that is what it refers to.